# How to find the four coordinates and erase drawing of an rubberband rectangle in C#

Tags: c#-3.0, erase, rubber-band

Hi I have tried to draw an rubberband rectangle on a form using the mouse in C#.

Problems

1) After the mouse release the rectangle disappears. [I want it to stay on the form]

2) I also need to find the coordinates of the four points of the drawn rectangle

3) I also need to erase the rectangle to draw a new one when necessary

Form :

[image]

---

### CODE

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace rubberbandrectangle
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Boolean bHaveMouse;
    Point ptOriginal = new Point();
    Point ptLast = new Point();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        bHaveMouse = true;
        ptOriginal.X = e.X;
        ptOriginal.Y = e.Y;
        ptLast.X = -1;
        ptLast.Y = -1;
    }

    private void MyDrawReversibleRectangle(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle();

        p1 = PointToScreen(p1);
        p2 = PointToScreen(p2);
        if (p1.X < p2.X)
        {
            rc.X = p1.X;
            rc.Width = p2.X - p1.X;
        }
        else
        {
            rc.X = p2.X;
            rc.Width = p1.X - p2.X;
        }
        if (p1.Y < p2.Y)
        {
            rc.Y = p1.Y;
            rc.Height = p2.Y - p1.Y;
        }
        else
        {
            rc.Y = p2.Y;
            rc.Height = p1.Y - p2.Y;
        }
        ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(rc,
                        Color.Red, FrameStyle.Dashed);
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        bHaveMouse = false;
        if (ptLast.X != -1)
        {
            Point ptCurrent = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            MyDrawReversibleRectangle(ptOriginal, ptLast);
        }
        ptLast.X = -1;
        ptLast.Y = -1;
        ptOriginal.X = -1;
        ptOriginal.Y = -1;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point ptCurrent = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        if (bHaveMouse)
        {
            if (ptLast.X != -1)
            {
                MyDrawReversibleRectangle(ptOriginal, ptLast);
            }
            ptLast = ptCurrent;
                MyDrawReversibleRectangle(ptOriginal, ptCurrent);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseDown);
        MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseUp);
        MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseMove);
        bHaveMouse = false;
    }





}
}
```

---

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) After the mouse release the rectangle disappears. [I want it to stay on the form]

You need to override the form's [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e40ahaz.aspx) method in order to continually draw your rectangle.  Right now, you draw it when the mouse moves, but it needs to be drawn afterwards, as well.

2) I also need to find the coordinates of the four points of the drawn rectangle

These should be in your ptOriginal and ptLast variables - What more do you need?

3) I also need to erase the rectangle to draw a new one when necessary

Just stop drawing the rectangle, and draw the new one in the OnPaint.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a similar thing but was amazed by the solution I found!
You have the coordinates right?
You can just use VisualBasic PowerPacks, it is included with my version of Visual Studio 2008

Here's a sample code that will draw a rectangle over a TextBox, i.e. I am giving it a custom border
[code]

```
Dim x = TextBox1.Location.X
Dim y = TextBox1.Location.Y
Dim width = TextBox1.Width
Dim height = TextBox1.Height
Dim ShapeContainer1 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer
Me.Controls.Add(ShapeContainer1)
Dim RectangleShape1 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape
ShapeContainer1.Shapes.AddRange(New Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Shape() {RectangleShape1})
RectangleShape1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(x - 1, y - 1)
RectangleShape1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(width + 1, height + 1)
RectangleShape1.BorderColor = Color.MistyRose
ShapeContainer1.Refresh()
```

Code is self describing but if you'd have any problem, just leave a message...
Yes, if you want to remove the rectangle, just dispose the controls(either the Rectangle or the ShapeContainer in whole), no painting, no hassle!